# Не могу получить код страницы megamarket.ru если используется параметр headless (необходим для фоновой работы selenium)

Tags: парсер, selenium, chromedriver

Не могу запустить парсер в фоновом режиме, так как появлется капча, если использовать `options.headless = False`, то все ок, но страница открывается во весь экран.

Цель запустить скрипт на vds сервере. Подскажите, если кто сталкивался с похожим случаем.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True #True
options.add_argument('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')


driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://megamarket.ru/")

print(driver.current_url)
print(driver.title)  # nowSecure
# Take a screenshot
driver.save_screenshot("screenshot.png")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Используй headless графический сервер. Например , Xvnc или Xspice.

```
Xspice --port 5901 --disable-ticketing :1  > /dev/null 2>&1 &  /opt/your/code
```

Comment: Не смог найти инструкцию как этим пользоваться, можно ли по подробнее или ссылку где почитать 